# AucTeX insert-environment C-c C-e (no label prompt)?

Tags: macros, emacs, auctex

Does anybody know how to configure Emacs or Auctex such that when you insert an environment for example with C-c C-e equation RET? Avoid having to type RET for (Optional) What label? question? Or completely stop being asked for any kind of label?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insertion of environment labels is controlled by the `LaTeX-label-alist` variable.  If you don't want environment labels, theoretically you would need to make that variable nil:

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-label-alist nil)
```

Unfortunately, this setting will be overridden for the environments provided by the `amsmath` package and the `longtable` environment.

---

A much more coarse solution would be to redefine the `LaTeX-label` function to do nothing.  Add the following to your `.emacs`

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (defun LaTeX-label (env))))
```

So you'll never be prompted for labels after inserting an environment with <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> or a section with <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd>.  You'll be able to manually add labels with <kbd>C-c C-m</kbd> `label` <kbd>RET</kbd> as usual.